# I am writing a max filter. This replaces each pixel RGB channel with the maximum channel intensity of the surrounding 9 pixels

Tags: c

Here is the code I am using.  When I run it, it doesn't seem to change anything in the image except the last 1/4 of it.  That part turns to a solid color.

```
    void maxFilter(pixel * data, int w, int h)
    {
    GLubyte tempRed;
    GLubyte tempGreen;
    GLubyte tempBlue;
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int pnum = 0;
    int pnumWrite = 0;
    for(i = 0 ; i < (h - 2); i+=3) {
    for(j = 0 ; j < (w - 2); j+=3) {
        tempRed = 0;
        tempGreen = 0;
        tempBlue = 0;
        for (k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++){

        if ((data[pnum].r) > tempRed){tempRed = (data[pnum + k].r);}
        if ((data[pnum].g) > tempGreen){tempGreen = (data[pnum + k].g);}
        if ((data[pnum].b) > tempBlue){tempBlue = (data[pnum + k].b);}

        if ((data[(pnum + w)].r) > tempRed){tempRed = (data[(pnum + w)].r);}
        if ((data[(pnum + w)].g) > tempGreen){tempGreen = (data[(pnum + w)].g);}
        if ((data[(pnum + w)].b) > tempBlue){tempBlue = (data[(pnum + w)].b);}

        if ((data[(pnum + 2 * w)].r) > tempRed){tempRed = (data[(pnum + 2 * w)].r);}
        if ((data[(pnum + 2 * w)].g) > tempGreen){tempGreen = (data[(pnum + 2 * w)].g);}
        if ((data[(pnum + 2 * w)].b) > tempBlue){tempBlue = (data[(pnum + 2 * w)].b);}
        pnum++;
        }
        pnumWrite = pnum - 3;
        for (k = 0 ; k < 3 ; k++){
            ((data[pnumWrite].r) = tempRed);
            ((data[pnumWrite].g) = tempGreen);
            ((data[pnumWrite].b) = tempBlue);

            ((data[(pnumWrite + w)].r) = tempRed);
            ((data[(pnumWrite + w)].g) = tempGreen);
            ((data[(pnumWrite + w)].b) = tempBlue);

            ((data[(pnumWrite + 2 * w)].r) = tempRed);
            ((data[(pnumWrite + 2 * w)].g) = tempGreen);
            ((data[(pnumWrite + 2 * w)].b) = tempBlue);
            pnumWrite++;
        }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: The indexing `pnum` to access `data[]` doesn't seem to be correct. `pnum` is always 0? Is this what you want? Also, you iterate over `i` and `j` but never use them?

Comment: Note that you are _not_ using opengl at all.

Comment: Pnum is indexed at the bottom with pnum++.  I and J are used to step through data.  Data is an image.  sou the outer loop steps through the height and the inner loop steps through the width.  Pnum indexes each time so I can access the pixel at that location.

Comment: I use OpenGL else where in the program.  Sorry.  Didnt realize I wasn't using it here.

Comment: Reading from `data` and also writing it may be a problem. Try with a new output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I can see several problems with that code - being difficult to follow not being the least!

I think your main problem is that the loop is (as you probably intended) run through `h/3 * w/3` times, once for each 3x3 block in the image.  But the `pnum` index runs only increases by `3` for each block, and reaches a maximum of about `h*w/3`, rather than the intended `h*w`.  That means that only the first third of your image will be affected by your filter.  (And I suspect your painting is done 'bottom-up', so that's why you see the lowest part change.  I remember .bmp files being structured that way, but perhaps there are others as well.)

The 'cheap' fix would be to add `2*w` at the right point, but nobody will ever understand that code again.  I suggest you rewrite your indexing instead, and explicitly compute `pnum` from `i` and `j` in each turn through the loop.  That can be improved on for readability, but is reasonably clear.

There's another minor thing: you have code like

```
if ((data[pnum].r) > tempRed){tempRed = (data[pnum + k].r);}
```

where the indexing on the right and on the left differ: this is probably also giving you results different from what you intended.

As Jongware points out, writing to the input array is always dangerous - your code is intended, I believe, to avoid that problem by only looking once into each 3x3 block, but his suggestion of a separate output array is very sensible - you probably don't want the blockiness your code gives anyway (you make each 3x3 block all one colour, don't you?), and his suggestion would let you avoid that.